# geting 419 page expire error in laravel when using payumoney payment status reponse back url

Tags: laravel, payment, payumoney

this is my payment gateway page

```
<?php

    $MERCHANT_KEY = "WTLZQBOb"; // add your id
    $SALT = "6MyvUWk9pP"; // add your id

    //$PAYU_BASE_URL = "https://test.payu.in";
    $PAYU_BASE_URL = "https://secure.payu.in";
    $action = '';
    $txnid = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20);
    $posted = array();
    $posted = array(
        'key' => $MERCHANT_KEY,
        'txnid' => $txnid,
        'amount' => 1,
        'firstname' => Auth::user()->name,
        'email' => Auth::user()->email,
        'productinfo' => 'PHP Project Subscribe',
        'surl' => 'http://infohp.in/admin/callback-pay-u-money',
        'furl' => 'http://infohp.in/admin/cancel-payment',
        'service_provider' => 'payu_paisa',
    );

    if(empty($posted['txnid'])) {
        $txnid = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $txnid = $posted['txnid'];
    }

    $hash = '';
    $hashSequence = "key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5|udf6|udf7|udf8|udf9|udf10";
    
    if(empty($posted['hash']) && sizeof($posted) > 0) {
        $hashVarsSeq = explode('|', $hashSequence);
        $hash_string = '';  
        foreach($hashVarsSeq as $hash_var) {
            $hash_string .= isset($posted[$hash_var]) ? $posted[$hash_var] : '';
            $hash_string .= '|';
        }
        $hash_string .= $SALT;

        $hash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $hash_string));
        $action = $PAYU_BASE_URL . '/_payment';
    } 
    elseif(!empty($posted['hash'])) 
    {
        $hash = $posted['hash'];
        $action = $PAYU_BASE_URL . '/_payment';
    }

?>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <script>
    var hash = '<?php echo $hash ?>';
    function submitPayuForm() {
      if(hash == '') {
        return;
      }
      var payuForm = document.forms.payuForm;
           payuForm.submit();
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="submitPayuForm()">
    Processing.....
        <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" name="payuForm"><br />
           
            <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo $MERCHANT_KEY ?>" /><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo $hash ?>"/><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="<?php echo $txnid ?>" /><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1" /><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?=Auth::user()->name?>" /><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" value="<?=Auth::user()->email?>" /><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="productinfo" value="PHP Project Subscribe"><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="surl" value="http://infohp.in/admin/callback-pay-u-money" /><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="furl" value="http://infohp.in/admin/cancel-payment" /><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="payu_paisa"  /><br />
            <?php
            if(!$hash) { ?>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            <?php } ?>
        </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is my URL link

```
<input type="hidden" name="surl" value="http://infohp.in/admin/callback-pay-u-money" /><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="furl" value="http://infohp.in/admin/cancel-payment" /><br />
```

I am trying to use payUmoney in my laravel 7 project i am geting error

When I am trying to get payuMoney payment response status and redirect in my URL page in laravel 7, can you please  help me how to resolve that problem.  please help me as soon as possible .

Answer (score 2):

except this route on app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php (except array)

```
$except = ['*cancel-payment*'];
```

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    protected $addHttpCookie = true;
    
    protected $except = [
        'http://infohp.in/admin/cancel-payment'
    ];
}

Comment: this is not currect, add this: $except = ['*cancel-payment*'];

Comment: @sachinbisht stars removed by stackoverflow i just edit answer now

Comment: can you please help i use this code but it is not working properly
 protected $except = [
        '*cancel-payment*'
    ];

Comment: @sachinbisht after this run php artisan optimize and php artisan cache:clear and check it again